# Check if non-valued query string exists in url with C#

Tags: c#, url, query-string

I've seen a couple examples of how to check if a query string exists in a url with C#:

`www.site.com/index?query=yes`

```
if(Request.QueryString["query"]=="yes")
```

But how would I check a string without a parameter? I just need to see if it exists.

`www.site.com/index?query`

```
if(Request.QueryString["query"] != null) //why is this always null?
```

I know there's probably a simple answer and I'll feel dumb, but I haven't been able to find it yet. Thanks!

Comment: If at all possible, don't try to provide information in that manor.  Either ensure that the caller sets a value to a query parameter to pass information through a query parameter, or if it doesn't make sense as a key/value pair then instead manipulate the query in another way.  Having a query parameter with no value adding information is going to be confusing to those using the site.

Comment: That makes good sense to me. I may not be able to change the URL though, since I didn't create it in the first place and my supervisor uses it for stats and such. I'll ask him if he's okay with switching it to a 'query=true' type query string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do not specify a value, the key will be automatically set to null, so you cannot check its existence.

In order to check if the value actually exists, you can check in the collection of **Values** equalling `null` if it contains your **Key**:

```
Request.QueryString.GetValues(null).Contains("query")
```

Comment: This works fine you just need to check for null after get values

Comment: Note to myself and others: this is *not* the same as `Request.QueryString[null].Contains("query")`, which will return True on `www.site.com/index?notmyquery`. `Request.QueryString[null]` returns a comma-delimited string, while `Request.QueryString.GetValues(null)` returns a string array.

Answer (score 8):

this is the fastest way to check it thanks to Ludovic's answer

```
if(Request.QueryString.GetValues(null)?.Contains("query")??false)
```

Comment: This is the best answer, as it doesn't break on `www.site.com/index?query=`.

Answer (score 5):

It returns `null` because in that query string it has no value for that key. I think the check you're looking for is this:

```
if(Request.QueryString.Keys.OfType<string>().Any(k => k == "query"))
```

or even:

```
if(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Any(k => k == "query"))
```

The latter is probably more appropriate because that array is already cached.

Comment: Neither of these seems to work. The AllKeys collection does return with a 1 Count, meaning the query string is in there, but the lambda expression can't find the key. It seems to be looking for the value?

Comment: Ah, figured it out. Your code works if the query string has a value. Otherwise the key shows up as null. Similar to what Grant said in his answer.

Answer (score 4):

If `query` was included as a parameter, but no value was specified, then the value of `query` will be null but it will still exist in `Request.QueryString.AllKeys`.

If `query` was not included, it won't exist in `Request.QueryString.AllKeys` at all.

Comment: This is actually the answer. I can't check for a specific key unless the key has a value. I'm not comfortable checking for a null key in AllKeys and just leaving it at that, so I'll have to add a value, as per Servy's comment.

Comment: @Emad Then upvote it if you found it useful. Why leave a comment on other answers?

Comment: I did up vote but usually people look straight to the answer marked as correct. I wanted everyone to see that there are other options. Your answer is right but in my opinion not the best. I even posted a modified answer myself.

Comment: This answer is wrong. If query was included as a parameter, but no value was specified, then the value of query will be null and the key will be null as well in Request.QueryString.AllKeys

Comment: @Cesar It helped a few people including the OP, at least. I can't unaccept it as the "best answer" for the OP. If another answer is better, I'd suggest upvoting it so it gets more visibility.

Comment: @GrantWinney I don't know how it did. In the case of the question asked `www.site.com/index?query` the key 'query' DOES NOT exist inside `Request.QueryString.AllKeys`, instead, null exists there. This is a fact. Matthew also pointed that out.

Comment: @DanielMiller If you're able to, can you weigh in on this? You had accepted this answer as the "best", but there have been other answers since then. If it seems to you like one of the others is better, selecting it as the "best" would lead future visitors in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: @GrantWinney Gosh, this was five years ago--no idea why I would've selected this as the answer if it hadn't worked (I was young and confused perhaps). I'll select another.

Answer (score 3):

Ludovic has the right answer. But I would like to offer a more robust version.

```
var valueEntries = Request.QueryString.GetValues((string)null) ?? new string[] {};
if (valueEntries.Contains("query", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    // value is specify in querystring
}
else
{
    // value is NOT specify in querystring
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is verbose and it works. [Here is a .NET Fiddle.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/y54Yxz)

```
@using System.Linq;

@{
    var empties = Request.Url.Query
        .Split('&')
        .Where(s => !s.Contains("=") || s.Last() == '=');

    var keyExistsAndIsEmpty = empties.Any(x => x.Contains("target-key")
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle has nothing to do with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if the value is null, then the key is also null in the `QueryString` collection. Your best bet is simply to assign a value to the query. There might be a way for you to rename the parameter so that this makes more semantic sense. For example instead of `www.site.com/index?getdocument=yes` you could do `www.site.com/index?action=getdocument`

However if you still want the url `www.site.com/index?query` to work, there is a way: don't use the `QueryString` at all and parse the URL manually:

```
string query = Request.RawUrl.Split('?')[1];
if (query == "query")
{
    // send the data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a null check to determine if a key exists when the "=" is not supplied since null means that the key wasn't in the query string.

The problem is that "query" is being treated as a value with a null key and not as a key with a null value.

In this case the key is also null inside `Request.QueryString.AllKeys`.

I used this generic method to "fix" the null key problem in the query string before using it. This doesn't involve manually parsing the string.

Usage example:

```
var fixedQueryString = GetFixedQueryString(Request.QueryString);
if (fixedQueryString.AllKeys.Contains("query"))
{
}
```

The method:

```
public static NameValueCollection GetFixedQueryString(NameValueCollection originalQueryString)
{
      var fixedQueryString = new NameValueCollection();

      for (var i = 0; i < originalQueryString.AllKeys.Length; i++)
      {
          var keyName = originalQueryString.AllKeys[i];

          if (keyName != null)
          {
              fixedQueryString.Add(keyName, originalQueryString[keyName]);
          }
          else
          {                       
              foreach (var keyWithoutValue in originalQueryString[i].Split(','))
              {
                  fixedQueryString.Add(keyWithoutValue, null);
              }              
          }
      }

      return fixedQueryString;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I Prefer to use:

```
If(Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("query")
{
    //
}
```